# Pass value of multiple selected checkboxes into multiple corresponding input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have this code:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" />A</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" />B</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" />C</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" />D</label><br />

<input name="selected_1" />
<input name="selected_2" />
<input name="selected_3" />

$(function() {
    $('input').on('click', function() {
        var values = [];
        $('input:checked').each(function() {
            values.push($(this).parent().text());
        });
        $('[name="selected_1"]').attr({value: values.join(', ')});
    });
});
```

The code above accurately passes the value of all selected checkboxes (comma-separated) to the input field [selected_1].

However, I want to pass the value of any of the selected checkbox into [name="selected_1"], the second selected checkbox value into [name="selected_2"] and the third selected checkbox to [name="selected_3"] in no given order. Then I want to limit the selection to a maximum of only three check-boxes selected in the form.

This fiddle [Limit Checkbox Selection](http://jsfiddle.net/vVxM2/) Demonstrates how limiting the selection is achieved.

Now, how do I pass the value of each checkbox selected into the corresponding input field using Javascript or JQuery 3.3.1?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to maintain some relationship between the checkboxes and inputs, so that when a checkbox is clicked, it's related input value is set, for this, you can use data attributes, like below

```
<label><input type="checkbox" data-input="selected_1" />A</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" data-input="selected_2"/>B</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" data-input="selected_3"/>C</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" data-input="selected_4"/>D</label><br />

<input name="selected_1" />
<input name="selected_2" />
<input name="selected_3" />
```

Now, onclick of checkbox, we can associate it with a textbox and set its value like below,

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
        var values = [];
        $('input:checked').each(function() {
            values.push($(this).parent().text());
        });
        $('[name="'+$(this).attr("data-input")+'"]').attr({value: values.join(', ')});
    });
});
```

[Working demo](https://codepen.io/ajanth2012/pen/MXaPpp)

I'm not sure why you're doing values.join(', ') instead of setting just a single checkbox value

[Working demo assigning single checkbox value to each input](https://codepen.io/ajanth2012/pen/zaeKdm)

Comment: Thank you Lone Wolf. Your hack works really good. I was not sure how to get the values passed so I had the Join(','). However, your solution works but it constrains a checkbox value to a particular input field. I am looking to pass any value selected to any input field, not particularly to a specific input field. eg. If you select checkbox D, it writes to input field 1, and other selections writes to the remaining input fields in no particular order. So a user may eventually submit values D, C & B and it writes to the [selected_1], [selected_2] and [selected_3] serially.